# Prove that $2^n3^{2n}-1$ is always divisible by 17

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that $2^n3^{2n} -1$ is always divisible by $17$.

I am very new to proofs and i was considering using proof by induction but I am not sure how to. I know you have to start by verifying the statement is true for the integer 1 but I dont know where to go from there.

Comment: I am very new to proofs and i was considering using proof by induction but I am not sure how to. I know you have to start by verifying the statement is true for the integer 1 but I dont know where to go from there.

Comment: Whatever you have tried, it is a good idea to incorporate your work in the question, so users see where you are stuck in your attempt to solve it using induction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the OP's statement that she's trying to do this inductively:

You want to prove that for all $n$, the statement "$2^n3^{2n}-1$ is divisible by $17$" is true.

The first thing to do is to notice that $2^n3^{2n}-1=18^n-1$.

Next, you need to prove your base case: that is, that plugging in $n=1$, the result is true.

Last, you need to show that *if* the result holds for a given $n$, it also holds for $n+1$; that is, assuming that $18^n-1$ is divisible by $17$, prove that $18^{n+1}-1$ is also divisible by $17$.

By way of a hint for this last part, consider writing $18^{n+1}=18\cdot 18^n=18^n+17\cdot 18^n$. Can you see any way to make use of this?

Answer (score 13):

$$2^n\cdot3^{2n}-1 = 18^n-1 = (18-1)(\cdots) = 17(\cdots)$$

Comment: Alternatively, $18^n-1 \equiv 1^n-1 \pmod {17}$.

Comment: @Rebecca, maybe add that as an answer - I'll upvote!

Comment: How did you take out $(18-1)$ as common? I see it as $18^n-18^0$, so, $18^0$ is common.

Comment: @Ramit, $18^n-1=18^n-1^n$, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_nth_powers

Comment: that's interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $2\cdot3^2=18$ and $18\equiv1\pmod{17}$

If you do not know that
$$
a\equiv b\pmod{p}\implies a^n=b^n\pmod{p}\tag{1}
$$
then $(1)$ can be proven by induction pretty easily.